# How fix __dirname not defined when using electron events with Vue?

Tags: vue.js, electron, vuex

I used [nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder) to create an electron app prepared with Vue/Vuex. It ships with files `main.js`, `background.js` including Vue component starting point. But I can't get the events to work. My attempt below yields `Uncaught ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined` when rendering (compile is fine).

Component: Splash.vue

```
<template>
    <div @click="open">open</div>      
</template>

<script>

const { ipcMain } = require('electron')

export default {
    methods: {
        open()
        {
            ipcMain.on('my-open-event', (event, arg) => {
                console.log(event, arg)
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

background.js

```
import { app, protocol, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'

...

app.on('my-open-event', async () => {
    try {
        "Will call some executable here";
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
})
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Full error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/electron/index.js:4)
    at Object../node_modules/electron/index.js (chunk-vendors.js:1035)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/Splash.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:6)
    at Module../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/Splash.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:986)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./src/components/Splash.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:2)
    at Module../src/components/Splash.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:1271)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same bug on almost exactly the same setup: In my case it's a Vue-Electron-Vuetify setup and I have modified vue.config.js: I'd paste it in here but it's too long. So I have pushed my changes to my repo on GitHub here: https://github.com/SethEden/electronVueJS-App

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To solve this I created a file `vue.config.js` in project root with content

```
module.exports = {
    pluginOptions: {
        electronBuilder: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I confirmed that this solution work perfectly. But WARNING because this solution open an Electron security issue explain here : https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content

Comment: It is working correctly, thanks... 
Node: v14.17.1
@vue/cli 4.5.13
Electron 13.1.2
Vuetify  v2

Comment: how to make this work in vitejs?

Comment: This solution does not work anymore

Answer (score 2):

There are two processes in electron, the main process and the renderer process. Your Vue component is the renderer process. In order to communicate between these two processes, you need inter-processes communication. So in your case, you'd define a channel perhaps in `background.js` using `ipcMain`. You'd write something like:

```js
ipcMain.on("my-custom-channel", (event, args) => handleEvent(event, args));
```

Then in your Vue component, you'd use the renderer process, ipcRendere, such as:

```js
import { ipcRenderer } from "electron";

export default {
    methods: {
        open() {
            ipcRenderer.send('my-custom-channel', "hello from Vue!")
        }
    }
}
```

Point is: you cannot use `app.on` for your custom events. `app.on` handles predefined electron events. Use `ipcMain.on` instead.

reference: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the solution described on this post
[How to import ipcRenderer in vue.js ? __dirname is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63615355/how-to-import-ipcrenderer-in-vue-js-dirname-is-not-defined)

In this way you can call window.ipcRenderer.send(channel, args...) from vue files.

Just make sure you configure preload.js on vue.config.js:

```
// vue.config.js - project root
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
       preload: 'src/preload.js'  //make sure you have this line added
    }
  }
}
```

Another solution can be found here https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-safely-set-up-an-electron-app-with-vue-and-webpack-556fb491b83 and it use __static to refer to preload file instead of configure it on vue.config.js. To make it work you can disable preload es-lint warning inside of BrowserWindow constructor:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
preload: path.resolve(__static, 'preload.js')
```

And make sure you added preload.js file on /public folder